# Python multiprocessing executes whole code and it is executing in wrong order

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have code running two processes. There are three problems:

1. When multiprocessing is used whole code is executed.
2. time.sleep at start pauses whole code, not after `print('hello', name, 'sleeping 1 second')` and after that the rest is executing without dealay as it shouldn't.
3. Processes are executed in reverse order.

Code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

print('--Beginning of code--')

def f(name):
    print('hello', name, 'sleeping 1 second')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('goodbye', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('Bob',))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('Tom',))
    p.start()
    p2.start()
    p.join()
    p2.join()

print('--end of code--')
```

Output:

```
--Beginning of code--
--Beginning of code--
--end of code--
hello Tom sleeping 1 second
goodbye Tom
--Beginning of code--
--end of code--
hello Bob sleeping 1 second
goodbye Bob
--end of code--
```

How the output should look like:

```
--Beginning of code--
hello Bob sleeping 1 second
hello Tom sleeping 1 second
goodbye Bob
goodbye Tom
--end of code--
```

I've tried searching and couldn't find any solution.
At first it couldn't even run but I've managed it to work.
I am using Python 3.8.1
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What happens when you leave off the last two .join statements? Could you look at an existing multi-thread problem and working solution?

Comment: What you are describing aren't problems they are what can be expected in multi processing: (1) every process is one instance of the (whole) program (2) see 1 (3) There is no order in multiprocessing.

Comment: why do You think it should looks like you describe?, the whole `multiprocessing` creates separate process which loads this whole module, and because this print with `--Beginn...` is in module scope it will be executed in every subprocess

Answer (score 0):

This also depends on the platform (Unix, Windows) and [start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).

You can get the expected results on Unix platform using `fork` method (it's the default method so no need to set it explicitly). The main process will [fork](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork) a child process and the child process will run only the target function (`f` in your case):

```
$ python test.py
--Beginning of code--
hello Bob sleeping 1 second
hello Tom sleeping 1 second
goodbye Bob
goodbye Tom
--end of code--
```

It looks like your script is using `spawn` method, most likely on Windows as this is the only method available on this platform. In this method the parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process (`python -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main...`) so the whole module is executed:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
...
```

Test:

```
$ python test.py
--Beginning of code--
--Beginning of code--
--end of code--
hello Bob sleeping 1 second
--Beginning of code--
--end of code--
hello Tom sleeping 1 second
goodbye Bob
goodbye Tom
--end of code--
```

Comment: I am using Windows and here `os.fork()` is not supported in python 3.8.
I have UI and processing script. I want them to share info and I was going to use multiprocessing but I thing this will be maybe too advanced for python beginner.
What else can I use for that? I was thinking about environment variables but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: It will be difficult to help without some more information so I would suggest you to open a new question and explain the problem you’re trying to solve. You can also try threads instead of multiprocessing but I’m not sure if this will help in your case without some more context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stretch but you can do it like:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def f(name):
    print('hello', name, 'sleeping 1 second')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('goodbye', name)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    f.has_been_called = False
    print('--Beginning of code--')

    f.has_been_called = True
    if f.has_been_called:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('Bob',))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('Tom',))
        p.start()
        p2.start()
        p.join()
        p2.join()

    print('--end of code--')
```